# siunitx: No \rad command available

Tags: siunitx

In the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) on page 37 is a `\rad` command which leads to an error. Is it a typo?

An example for using of this unit (created with MATLAB):
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `siunitx` package used to have the units `\rad` and the derived `\mrad`. However, since it is not in the SI, it has been dropped with the release of version 2 of `siunitx`.

On page 37 the dropped units are listed, `\rad` skipped the list for some reason and only `\mrad` appears.

If you need it, add

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\rad}{rad}
```

to your document preamble. Beware that the unit is *strongly discouraged* in chapter 5.2 of the style guide for U.S. National Institute of Standards and Technology authors.

---

### Added after OP posted an image

The unit in the diagrams you posted is the *radian*, for which the name exists in `siunitx` and is `\radian`.

Comment: Just so others don't make the same mistake that I just did: `\rad != \radian`.  I use the package but forgot this.  It appears now (with the edit) that OP made the same mistake.

Comment: Hello @egreg! Thank you for your answer! I didn't knew about the discourage. But the universities are still using this unit for the teachings. Also MATLAB using it, see me edited question.

Comment: @Su-47 That's ***not*** the rad unit!, but the “radians”, for which you need `\radian`.

Comment: @egreg if "rad" and "radian" don't refer to the same unit, what is "rad" the unit of?

Comment: @debsim I guess that the older unit `\rad` was about radioactivity (radiation absorbed dose), now replaced by the gray (Gy).